# What does "Swift is build on top of C and Objective C without constraints of C compatibility" means?

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

“Swift is a new programming language for iOS, macOS, watchOS, and tvOS apps that builds on the best of C and Objective-C, without the constraints of C compatibility. ”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3).” iBooks. https://itun.es/es/jEUH0.l

What does it mean by "without constraints of C compatibility"? What kind of constraints it's referring to?

Comment: To slightly rephrase @MartinR's comment, Objective-C has to be able to handle regular C code - that's what's meant by "constraints of C compatibility".

Comment: *(I inadvertently deleted my comment, here it is again:)* Objective-C is an *extension* of C (all valid C code is also valid Objective-C code). Swift is not.

Comment: It is a marketing slogan. Don't pay attention to it. However, the best of Objective-C is lost: the late binding.

Answer (score 0):

All of them.

- Syntax
- Memory model
- Operator precedence
- Calling convention
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

C programming language is a structured programming language... Objective C is an object oriented language and an evolution of C(similar as C++ is an evolution of C too).... The term constraints in your question refers to the limitations which arise in this modern age as C not being an object oriented language...

Comment: C is structured.  It doesn't have first-class objects, but it has structure.

Answer (score 0):

> without the constraints of C compatibility

**C** is great, but old programming language with many constraints.

**Objective-C** is just a thin layer atop **C**. It is also pretty old and has its own constraints. It is fully compatible with **C**, which means that is possible to compile any **C** program with an **Objective-C** compiler. You can even mix **Objective-C** and **C** code in one source file, just, because they are almost the same thing.

**Swift** on the other hand is totally new and modern language. While designing **Swift** Apple took best (features, patterns, ideas) of **C**, **Objective-C**, and other programming languages.

It is hard to tell the exact constraints Apple is referring to. Basically, this is everything that makes adding new modern features or enhancements to **Objective-C** difficult or impossible work to do.